# Showing notifications at specific time error - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'd like to show my users a notification at specific times every day.
I've looked through tons of examples and questions, but I still have a problem - the notification just won't show up.

This is the BroadcastReceiver class -

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context con;
final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    con = context;

    showNotification();

}
public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    //After after 30 seconds
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 5 , pi); 
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}


/**
 * Creates a notification and shows it in the OS drag-down status bar
 */
private void showNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(con)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Hello")
    .setContentText("Hello")
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
    .setTicker("HELLO!")
    .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent resultIntent=new Intent(con, ViewMenu.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(con,0,resultIntent,0);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

     NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
         (NotificationManager) con.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     mNotificationManager.notify(90, mBuilder.build());
     Toast.makeText(con, "TEST4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

And this this how I set it up on the main Activity -

```
alarm = new testy.app.Notifications.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver();
alarm.SetAlarm(this);
```

I've also registered the BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest -

```
    <!-- Broadcast receiver -->
    <receiver  android:name="testy$app$Notifications$AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver</receiver>
```

Will appreciate any suggestion,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend follow this guide `http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/` is the one that leaves all doubts for me!